# Toubleshooting ECS container logs going to sqs

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-sqs, filebeat

I am trying to trouble shoot an issue. I have a set of logs from ecs that are to be sent to an sqs queue. The container logs show that the logs are being sent. However, when I poll the sqs queue none of the messages are received.

[image]
[image]

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
2021-10-06T22:16:30.330Z ERROR [input.s3] s3/collector.go:137 handleSQSMessage failed: json unmarshal sqs message body failed at offset 1 with syntax error: invalid character 'T' looking for beginning of value {"queue_url": "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/721086286010/filebeat-cloudtrail-sqs", "region": "us-east-1"}
```

This has been an ongoing issue with elastic.

Comment: "I have a set of logs from ecs that are to be sent to an sqs queue." please show how you did this.

Comment: The logs are sent from ecs containers to an sqs queue. How ever I run into thi error: `2021-10-06T22:16:30.330Z ERROR [input.s3] s3/collector.go:137 handleSQSMessage failed: json unmarshal sqs message body failed at offset 1 with syntax error: invalid character 'T' looking for beginning of value {"queue_url": "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/721086286010/filebeat-cloudtrail-sqs", "region": "us-east-1"}.

Comment: The comment you just added should instead be part of your question. Please edit your question to include all details. Also, while that error message is indeed an important detail, you still haven't explained how you configured the logs to go to SQS. Saying "the logs are sent from ecs" isn't an explanation. Sending logs to SQS isn't a default behavior of ECS, so how did you set it up?